# Rails how to build a hash from results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a table on Db with two fields: `group` and `text`

I want to retrieve all records and convert into an hash grouped by the `group` field, and containing an array of all texts, something like this:

```
{
    'group_1': ['text1','text2',...]
    'group_2': ['text1','text2',...]
    'group_3': ['text1','text2',...]
}
```

I acomplish it partially with this

```
MyModel.all.group_by(&:group)
```

but it returns an array with all the full AR object, i just want an array of all the text strings

I was trying with `map` but I can figure out how to do this without using `each`

Any idea?

Comment: I would like to know different ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyModel.all.select([:text, :group]).group_by(&:group)
```

If you wanted to use an iterator (ex: `each`/`map`), here is how you would do it:

```
grouped_models = MyModel.all.group_by(&:group)
grouped_models.map do |group, models|
  grouped_models[group] = models.map(&:text)
end

grouped_models
# => { 'group_1' => ['text1', 'text2'], 'group_2' => ['text'] }
```

Comment: It returns a model not text, and it gives me this warning: DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead.